# Commenting out a wrong bridge

Tags: bridge

I'm running a system tor; `/etc/tor/torrc` has both `UseBridges 1` and `ExcludeExitNodes {us},{au},{ca},{nz},{gb},{fr}` set. It runs OK, but I have a lot of bridges listed and one of them is apparently in the exclude nodes, since I'm constantly getting a `Not using bridge at [scrubbed]: it is in ExcludeNodes.` error in my console.
Is there a way to find out which bridge is causing it and edit `torrc` to stop trying to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `SafeLogging 0` for your tor to determine the bridge. After the problem will be fixed - set it to `SafeLogging 1` to ensure no leaks in your logs. Here is the [official documentation](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#SafeLogging) cite:

> SafeLogging 0|1|relay
>   Tor can scrub potentially sensitive strings from log messages (e.g. addresses) by replacing them with the string [scrubbed]. This way logs can still be useful, but they don’t leave behind personally identifying information about what sites a user might have visited.
>
> If this option is set to 0, Tor will not perform any scrubbing, if it is set to 1, all potentially sensitive strings are replaced. If it is set to relay, all log messages generated when acting as a relay are sanitized, but all messages generated when acting as a client are not. (Default: 1)

Comment: Oh. Great, thanks for that and a link to the documentation.